How to send several vars to client
I want to send to client many objects and one var, but i don't understand how to choose response that i want and create the var on client.
Server code:
var isAdmin = false;
app.get('/main', async (req, res) => {
  let cards = await CardFest.find();
  res.send(cards);
  res.send(isAdmin);
})

Client code:
async loadFests(){
  let response = await axios.get('/main');
  this.fests = response.data.cards;
  this.isAdmin = response.data.isAdmin;
}

But it, of course, doesn't work, because i can't find information how can i choose response.data that i need.

Server code:
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
app.use(cors())

var isAdmin = false;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    let cards = 'Hello'
    const object = {
      cards,
      isAdmin
    }
    res.json(object);
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('http://localhost:3000/')) // http://localhost:3000/

Client code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="loadFests()">Load Fests</button>
    <script>
    async function loadFests(){
        axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000';
        let response = await axios.get('/');
        const cards = response.data.cards;
        const isAdmin = response.data.isAdmin;
        console.log(`cards: ${cards}`)
        console.log(`isAdmin: ${isAdmin}`)
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>


ty, but your code does not work, there is the error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isAdmin')
    at Proxy.loadFests

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cards')
    at Proxy.loadFests


there is no data in object, i try to log - undefined.

the problem in your code is that you don't need to indicate 'object', if you write : response.data.cards it will work

I edited the code and wrote a fully working code, you could use res.json(object) or res.send(object)
